# Mock RxJava async http call

Tags: java, junit, mockito, rx-java

I am facing some trouble in mocking a RxJava function which makes some HTTP call. I am using JUnit and Mockito.

```
//Customer.java extends ServiceManager
public Observable<String> getCustomerDetails(String uuidData){
    String api = "http://someapi.com/" + uuidData;
    return callHttps(api, getHeader(),
            "",
            HttpMethod.GET)
            .doOnError(failure -> logger.error("Error was raised while calling Profile Save of ORCH API:"
                    + failure.getMessage()))
            .doOnNext(httpClientResponse -> {
                logger.info("");
            })
            .concatMap(RxHelper::toObservable)
            .reduce(Buffer.buffer(), Buffer::appendBuffer)
            .map(buffer -> buffer.toString("UTF-8"))
            .map(entries -> entries);
}

private MultiMap getProfileHeader(){
    MultiMap headers = MultiMap.caseInsensitiveMultiMap();
    headers.add("Accept","application/json");
    return headers;
}


public class ServiceManager {
    @Inject
    @Named("httpsClient")
    private HttpClient httpsClient;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceManager.class);

    public Observable<HttpClientResponse> callHttps(String url, MultiMap headers, String body, HttpMethod httpMethod) {
        return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            HttpClientRequest httpClientRequest = httpsClient.requestAbs(httpMethod, url);
            httpClientRequest.exceptionHandler(event -> {
               logger.error("Exception was raised :" + event.getMessage());
            });
            httpClientRequest.headers().addAll(headers);
            RxHelper
                    .toObservable(httpClientRequest)
                    .subscribe(subscriber);

            httpClientRequest.end(body);
        });
    }
}
```

How do I mock the `callHttps` function, so that it returns me a `HttpClientRequest` mocked response. An alternate way for me is to use WireMock, but I want to find a way by mocking above functions.

Comment: In our project we create real mock services, to prove precisely real latency, and possible communication problems. With Mockito as far as I know you cannot create a request, it will just mocked.

Comment: Instead of extending ServiceManager you may rather include it as a field and then use dependency injection to inject a mock implementation of ServiceManager that provides you fake http responses.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Customer` doesn't have to be final, you can use the [Self-Shunt Pattern](http://blog.ncortes.com/2013/06/21/the-self-shunt-unit-testing-pattern/). Basically, in this pattern, you extend your class under test to override methods with new mock functionality. So you would extend `Customer` and override `callHttps()` so that it doesn't actually do anything except record that it was called so that you can verify that it was actually called.

Note that I'm not advocating that you *should* test your code like this. Usually use of this pattern is indicative of [code that could be restructured](http://kaczanowscy.pl/tomek/2010-09/say-no-to-self-shunt). So, if you can, abandon the inheritance entirely. That being said, if you have to, try using something akin to the sample code below:

```
public class CustomerTest {
  @Mock
  private Observable<HttpClientResponse> mockObservable;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void getCustomerDetailsCallsCallHttps() {
    CustomerSelfShunt customerUnderTest = new CustomerSelfShunt();
    // Call the getCustomerDetails method. Should call overridden version of
    // callHttps() that sets callHttpsInvoked.
    Observable<String> actualObservable = customerUnderTest.getCustomerDetails("foo");
    assertEquals(this.mockObservable, actualObservable);
    assertTrue(customerUnderTest.callHttpsInvoked);
  }

  private class CustomerSelfShunt extends Customer {
    boolean callHttpsInvoked = false;

    public Observable<HttpClientResponse> callHttps(String url, MultiMap headers, String body, HttpMethod httpMethod) {
      // do nothing implementation, just record that this method was called.
      callHttpsInvoked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. Mockito provides spy facility to assist with this situation.  (although its use usually indicates code that should be restructured)

Example (simplified - and in this case I had to mock the HttpClientResponse as I was unable to create a concrete instance - but at least you avoid mocking Observable):

```
package com.sbp;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static rx.Observable.just;

import io.vertx.core.MultiMap;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpClientResponse;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import rx.Observable;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustomerTest {

    public static class ServiceManager {

        public Observable<HttpClientResponse> callHttps(String url, MultiMap headers, String body,
                HttpMethod httpMethod) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class Customer extends ServiceManager {

        public Observable<String> getCustomerDetails(String uuidData) {
            return callHttps("", null, null, null).map(r -> r.getHeader(""));
        }
    }

    @Spy
    private Customer customer;

    @Test
    public void getCustomerDetailsCallsCallHttps() {
        HttpClientResponse mockResponse = mock(HttpClientResponse.class);
        when(mockResponse.getHeader(anyString())).thenReturn("test");
        when(customer.callHttps(any(), any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(just(mockResponse));

        String headerValue = customer.getCustomerDetails("uuid").toBlocking().single();

        assertEquals("test", headerValue);
    }
}
```

2. Subclass and Override - here is an excellent article rooted from the testing legacy code book that explains the approach and when it is appropriate to use - https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/test-after-in-java-subclass-and-override
3. Break the inheritance model and inject an instance of ServiceManager into the instance of Customer. You will then be able to mock ServiceManager in the test of Customer using standard Mockito constructs - and - you will be able to test ServiceManager independently from its subclasses.